# TeXstudio: \ref not showing a "blank" placeholder

Tags: texstudio

When using completion on `\ref{}` I get a list of available labels (I'm running TexStudio 2.10.8). That's all fine, but when the list is long, it's hard to find the proper label from the dropdown list. It would be convenient for the `\ref{}` label list to start with a "blank" label, similar to `\eqref{label}`.

[image] vs. [image]

I've tried creating a `.cwl` file in `~/.config/texstudio/` and in `~/.config/texstudio/completion/user/` folder with only one entry

`\ref{label}#n`

or 

`\ref{label}#r`

but none of these work. Is there any way to make this possible?

Answer (score 1):

As of TeXstudio 2.10.8 you cannot do anything about this, because there was a hardcoded special handling.

Will be resolved in future versions without you having to do any changes.